# bootstrap 3: dynamic modal box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I work with bootstrap 3.0 modal box for show/add image url into input box after click in dynamic image link and choose image from iframe modal box(image manager).

PHP/HTML :

```
<div class="filesmap">
    <input id="video-12" class="form-control" type="text" name="video[]" value="'.$url.'">
</div> <span class="filesicon"><a id="video-12" data-target="#myModal" href="#" data-toggle="modal" type="button"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-browse"></i></a></span>

<div class="filesmap">
    <input id="video-90" class="form-control" type="text" name="video[]" value="'.$url.'">
</div> <span class="filesicon"><a id="video-90" data-target="#myModal" href="#" data-toggle="modal" type="button"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-browse"></i></a></span>

<div class="filesmap">
    <input id="video-80" class="form-control" type="text" name="video[]" value="'.$url.'">
</div> <span class="filesicon"><a id="video-80" data-target="#myModal" href="#" data-toggle="modal" type="button"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-browse"></i></a></span>
```

In modal box(static) :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:0px; margin:0px width: 560px;">
                <iframe width="560" height="400" src="/dialog.php?type=0&fldr=&field_id=video&&akey=dsflFWR9u2xQa" frameborder="0" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; "></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOW, for add image url from modal box to input box I add dynamic id for input box(example : `id="video-90"`) and sync with `field_id` (iframe src).

I need to open modal box for each input box with dynamic iframe/src link like this:

```
src="/dialog.php?type=0&fldr=&field_id=video-12&&akey=dsflFWR9u2xQa"

src="/dialog.php?type=0&fldr=&field_id=video-90&&akey=dsflFWR9u2xQa"

src="/dialog.php?type=0&fldr=&field_id=video-80&&akey=dsflFWR9u2xQa"
```

my mean is after click link modal open for same video id (iframe src).

How to can I create this ?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understood your question right 
but if you mean that all the modals contain the same content try this solution it worked for me

1- the ids for each modal should be different example

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-'different-id'">
...
</div>
```

2- this also should be reflected on the data-target within your  that triggers the modal

```
data-target="#myModal-'different-id'"
```

3- i also suggest triggering the modal using this jquery function *

```
$(function () { $("[data-toggle='modal']").modal();});
```

- if the modal is active without triggering use this function instead

  $(function () { $("[data-toggle='modal']").modal("hide");});